# Javascript, filtering array of objects and return all the unique objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, filtering

I have an array of objects, that contains properties that are objects:

```
let allPersons = [
    { id: "abcdefg",
      name: "tom",
      ...
      phone: {
         brand: "blah"
         id: "hijklm"
         ...
     }
   },
   { id: ....}, {...}, {...}
];
```

What I need to do is filter those objects and returning all the phones, filtering them by id so all phones returned are unique.

I tried to retrieve first all the phones:

```
// allPersons is the full array mentioned above
let phones = [...new Set(allPersons.map(person => person.phone))];
```

then I tried to return all the unique phones, but unsuccessfully:

```
let result = phones.map(phone => phone.id).filter((value, index, self) => self.indexOf(value) === index)
```

This returns only the unique ids of the phones, but I want the entire object. What can I do?

UPDATE:
phone Ids are NOT unique, e.g. nokia3310 has id 1, nokia3330 has id 2, etc: so tom and john can have the same phone and phone ids could be duplicated!

Comment: Are you meaning the `Id` of the Object, or the `Phone Id`?

Comment: Aren't the phone's IDs unique?

Comment: @AndresGardiol yes they are unique but I want the entire phone object in return

Comment: @berkobienb the phoneId !

Comment: @Diego, if you want the whole phone object returned then check my answer, it gets the whole phone object from each object and stores them in an array which you can use

Comment: Well, actually phone IDs are unique. But phones can be the same in a different person. So @RedemptionOkoro in your answer you will have the same repeated phones in the array if 2 or more people have the same phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make an object indexed by IDs instead, then take the object's values:

```
const phonesById = Object.fromEntries(
  allPersons.map(
    ({ phone }) => [phone.id, phone]
  )
);
const uniquePhones = Object.values(phonesById);
```

Comment: omg I didn't know `fromEntries` even existed, nor I knew I could map an entire object `{phone}` written in that way! thanks so much, I could never did it alone

Comment: may you please explain the `map` part? i don't think i've understood how it works :)

Comment: You can check the docs for more clarity: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/map 
What map does is basically creates a new array with the results of the call to the indicated function applied to each of its elements. The ´{ phone }´ part is destructuring the "person" object

Comment: @Diego `.map` transforms one array into another. Here, it transforms each `person` into an entry: a key-value pair for a new object, in the form of an array with 2 values. `Object.fromEntries` will have later entry keys overwrite earlier keys, so that's how the de-duplication works.

Comment: you mean each `phone` into an entry?

Comment: I finally got it writing them in separate functions :) I've never seen the `({phone}) => [phone.id, phone]` block, I thought I had to write `({phone}) => function { stuff... }`

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to get the phone object in each object of the array, then the code below will do that for you.

It gets the phone object and stores it in a

```
var objArr = [
    {id: "abcdefg", name: "tom", phone: {brand: "blah", id: "hijklm"}},
    {id: "guidiuqwbd", name: "john", phone: {brand: "hihihih", id: "ayfva"}},
    {id: "yuygeve", name: "doe", phone: {brand: "hahahah", id: "cqcqw"}}
]

var allPhoneObjects = [];
objArr.forEach(function(currObj){
    var phoneObj = currObj.phone;
    allPhoneObjects.push(phoneObj);
});
console.log(allPhoneObjects);
```

Comment: I think the question is not clear on that. When he say "filtering them by id so all phones returned are unique." It makes me think that phone's IDs may not be unique

Comment: If only he could make an edit to his question, making it more specific and clearer

Answer (score 0):

I propose you the following solution

```
let uniques = new Set();
const phones = allPersons.filter(({phone}) => (
  uniques.has(phone.id) ? false : !!uniques.add(phone.id)
)).map(p => p.phone)
```

Basically, we define a `Set` to record `ids` of the phones already processed, and a `filter` function on the `allPersons` array, that returns only the phones not already in the Set. We complete with the `map` to extract only the portion of JSON needed

**EDIT**
You can use just one function on the `allPersons` array using the `reduce` function

```
let uniques = new Set();
const phones = allPersons.reduce( (filtered, {phone}) => {
  if (!uniques.has(phone.id)) {
     filtered.push(phone);
     uniques.add(phone.id);
  }
  return filtered
}, [])
```

Comment: thanks, but with this implementation is returned the entire person object (which could anyway be useful!), but for now i need to return only the phone object for each person, put it in an array, and be sure there are not duplicated phones! (looking their id)

Comment: hi @Diego . I just ran now the code a second time, just to make sure I didn't messed up, but the returned array is an array of phones, and not the whole person .... If you run it, you will get something like `[{brand: "Nokia", id: "abc123"}, {brand: "Sony", id: "def456"}, {brand: "Apple", id: "ghi789"}]`